# multiply counted rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

is it possible to use count with an extra column which states the quantity?
lets call the table foo and it looks like this:

```
| title | qty |
|   a   |  1  |
|   b   |  1  |
|   b   |  2  |
|   a   |  3  |
|   a   |  1  |
```

I am doing a query:
SELECT title, COUNT(title) count FROM foo GROUP BY title

the result looks like this:

```
| title | count |
|   a   |   3   |
|   b   |   2   |
```

what I would actually like to get:

```
| title | count |
|   a   |   5   |
|   b   |   3   |
```

I am sure there must be a really easy way to do this.
There are many different titles, so i cannot count each title separately, there is 50-100 different titles they are being added by the user.

Comment: Simply use `SUM(qty)` instead of `COUNT(title)`.

Comment: yeah, this actually was this simple. i was overthinking it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use SUM(returns the sum of values) instead of COUNT(returns the number of rows returned by the query).

Comment: as i mentioned in a comment before, i was desperately overthinking an easy issue... thanks